# React native - Impossible to connect to dev server with server started without Expo

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I work on a project on react native and i can't live reload when the file change on the disk.
For infos :
- The metro server is running on 8081
- i did a adb reverse
- i use react-native run-android
- live reload is enable on the emulator device.
- I don't use expo

when i start the server i have my app running but when i tap RR for reloading the app i have the issue: "could not connect to develpopment server".

I don't know what to do !!

Everytime i make a change on a file, i need the bundle the app and start the metro server..

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: browse localhost:8081 to check if your metro server is running, sometimes it stops after installing

Comment: metro is stuck on loading depency graph, done and his not building the project.. i have acces to the metro server on my emulator so i don't know why he don't watch file to change

Comment: to watch for changes you should enable hot reloading

Comment: I found the solution, i'm on windows 10 and i needed to upgrade to the latest version of RN and add the localhost route to the emulator